# Returning a handler from a struct method in Golang gives error

Tags: go

I am trying to return a handler function from a Controller

In my `controllers/item.go` file:

```
package controllers

import (
 // ...
)

type Controller struct{}

func (c Controller) GetItems(db *sql.DB) http.Handler {
    return http.Handler(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      // ...
    })
}
```

In my `main.go` file:

```
func main() {
    db = db.Connect()
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    controllers := controllers.Controller{}

    router.HandleFunc("/items", controllers.GetItems(db)).Methods("GET")
}
```

You can see I am using `mux`. My problem is I have not been able to return the handler function. I keep getting this error:

```
 cannot convert func literal (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) to type http.Handler:
    func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You probably just need `http.HandlerFunc(...)` rather than `http.Handler(...)`, but without showing your actual error, that's only a guess.

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: My guess was right. Use `http.HandlerFunc()`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot arbitrarily convert a function to an `http.Handler`, but the `http` package does provide a convenient `http.Handler` struct type, which satisfies the `http.Handler` interface, and you can return an instance of this type easily:

```
func (c Controller) GetItems(db *sql.DB) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
         // ...
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works:

```
func (c Controller) GetItems(db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
          //...
  } 
}
```

I have changed the return type to `http.HandlerFunc`and removed the wrapper from the returned function.

Comment: This works, but I think it is better to keep `http.HandlerFunc` as an implementation detail (just a tool to create an `http.Handler`) and only expose `http.Handler` in the public interface of the package.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc): *The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of ordinary functions as HTTP handlers.*